# Como crear un proyecto nuevo en android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android

Pensaran que la pregunta es tonta pero no es asi, instale android studio version 2.2 tengo el jdk 1.8 instalado, nunca he usado android studio por lo que se instala y se configura por defecto, al iniciarse le doy la ruta de mi SDK, luego de esto trato de crear mi primer proyecto , le doy el nombre al proyecto selecciono la api de android y despues me sale una ventana que dice installing prerequisites debajo me muestra la ruta de mi sdk y un panel de texto en blanco, y no me deja dar siguiente ni nada por el estilo solo me deja la opcion de cancelar agradeceria mucho la ayuda

Comment: Arnold, Podrías agregar una imagen de lo que describes?

Comment: Me he fijado y al especificarle la api de android me dice lo siguiente Stats load Failed. Value must be out of date

Comment: el sitio no me deja añadir las fotos de forma facil si me das tu email te las envio a tu correo

Comment: Prueba de Instalar la versión estable de Android Studio la 2.1.2 ya que la 2.2 es la preview, puedes tener ambas, pero cuando instalas la preview te coge la configuración de la estable y se autoconfigura con lo nuevo.

Comment: Para poder resolver esta duda te dejare el link de una pagina en la cual explica paso a paso como crear el proyecto en android debido a que muchas veces hay problemas con el sdk o la variable JAVA_HOME:
http://picarcodigo.blogspot.mx/2013/10/crear-un-proyecto-en-android.html

Comment: Tuve un error parecido al instalar android studio, si te vas a `File` y luego a `Settings` (creo que desde la pantalla de inicio también puedes llegar a este menú con las opciones de abajo a la izquierda de la pantalla) , tienes una opcion de `Android SDK`, te sale una lista con las diferentes plataformas de SDK. Comprueba que la que usas en tu proyecto esta marcada, en su defecto prueba cambiar a otro tipo de SDK, yo por lo general uso `Android 4.1(Jelly Bean)`